# How to solve following equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Answer of this question is following but I don't know how to solve it if some one can solve, please give the solution

[image]

Comment: substitute $y=f(\xi)\frac{d\rho}{d \xi}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\xi{f}(\xi)\frac{d\varrho}{d\xi}=-2D\frac{d}{d\xi}\Big({f}(\xi)\frac{d\varrho}{d\xi}\Big)$$
Let
$${f}(\xi)\frac{d\varrho}{d\xi}=G(\xi)$$
Then
$$\xi{G(\xi)}=-2D\frac{dG(\xi)}{d\xi}$$
Thus
$${f}(\xi)\frac{d\varrho}{d\xi}=G(\xi)=G_{0}\exp\Big(-\frac{\xi^{2}}{4D}\Big)$$
Thus
$$\varrho(\xi)=G_{0}\int\frac{\exp\Big(-\frac{\xi^{2}}{4D}\Big)}{{f}(\xi)}d\xi$$